reinterpret_cast always check even branch omitted by if constexpr
typedef void* MaaWin32Hwnd;
typedef uint32_t MaaMacWindowId;

#if defined(_WIN32)
typedef MaaWin32Hwnd MaaHwnd;
#elif defined(__APPLE__)
typedef MaaMacWindowId MaaHwnd;
#else
typedef int MaaHwnd;
#endif

inline std::string from_hwnd(MaaHwnd hwnd)
{
    if constexpr (std::is_pointer_v<MaaHwnd>) {
        return std::format("{:#018x}", reinterpret_cast<size_t>(hwnd));
    }
    else {
        return std::format("{:#018x}", static_cast<size_t>(hwnd));
    }
}

Consider code above. On macos, MaaHwnd is uint32_t, and from_hwnd should use the lower branch. But clang always raise error:
type.hpp :error: reinterpret_cast from 'MaaHwnd' (aka 'unsigned int') to 'size_t' (aka 'unsigned long') is not allowed
[build]    23 |         return std::format("{:#018x}", reinterpret_cast<size_t>(hwnd));

I know I can use function overload instead to make it work, but I'm wondering why clang tries to compile (or maybe check?) the upper branch.

constexpr branch may be omitted only in template functions:  https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if#:~:text=since%20C%2B%2B17)-,Constexpr%20if,-The%20statement%20that

Thanks! I'v changed the condition to an expression of a fake template argument and it works.

A fake template isn't the solution. It's only guaranteed to work if the error you want to silence depends on the template parameter. E.g. you could template this function, making MaaHwnd a template parameter.
